# How do I disable JQuery below certain device widths?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am looking to stop JQuery functions at mobile device widths (768px and below).
I have tried using $(window).width() to detect screen width, then use an if statement, but can't seem to get it working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var resolution = $(window).width();
  if (resolution >= 768) {
    $('.img-1').hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({right: "350px"},1000);
        $('#desc1').show(1000);
    });
    $('.img-1').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({right: "0px"},1000);
        $('#desc1').hide(1000);
    });
  } else {
    // NO SCRIPT
  }
});
```

Here is a link to a codepen of it: http://codepen.io/SRBET/pen/dOJoJb/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var resolution = $(window).width();
if (resolution > 768) {

  $(document).ready(function(){

  $('.img-1').hover(function(){
     $(this).animate({right: "350px"},1000);
     $('#desc1').show(1000);
 });
 $('.img-1').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({right: "0px"},1000);
    $('#desc1').hide(1000);
 });
});

} else {
// NO SCRIPT
}
```

Use the if condition before ready function. its working in code panel (I have tried it on chrome). Also remove equal sign if you want that it should not work on 768px.

Comment: @A.Wolff : check the comments and I have changed the position of if condition. now ready function will not execute for small width devices.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery $(selector).off() is used to remove the Jquery event.
Find the solution in updated codepen :
http://codepen.io/Debabrata89/pen/xRpwOG  .
Refresh the page below 768px to see that $('.img-1').hover() function being not called.Also along with $(document).ready() ,use $(window).resize() with debouncing function and write the logic inside it.

```
 var resolution = $(window).width();
if (resolution >= 768) {

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.img-1').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({right: "350px"},1000);
    $('#desc1').show(1000);
});
$('.img-1').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({right: "0px"},1000);
    $('#desc1').hide(1000);
});
});
  } else {
$('.img-1').off("hover");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.img-2').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({right: "350px"},1000);
    $('#desc2').show(1000);
});
$('.img-2').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({right: "0px"},1000);
    $('#desc2').hide(1000);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

We want to achieve 2 things.

- Make sure the effects do net get applied on mobile-screen devices.
- Make sure that the effects **do** get applied when the screen width changes to more than the 768px.

So, how can we achieve this in the most logical way possible?

```js
var resetEvents = function() {
 $('.img-1').off()
 $('#desc1').off()
 checkScreen();
}

var checkScreen = function() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
    $('.img-1').hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({right: "350px"},1000);
        $('#desc1').show(1000);
    });
    $('.img-1').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({right: "0px"},1000);
        $('#desc1').hide(1000);
    });
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 resetEvents();
 $(window).resize(function() {
  resetEvents()
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="img-1">hi, i'm img-1</div>
<div style="display:none;" id="desc1">hi, i'm desc1</div>
```

(Open in full screen to see the events working, and small screen to see them disabled)

I've wrapped your code inside multiple functions, and call the first one on `$(document).ready()`. The first function resets all the current event listeners on the elements. Then calls the second function.

In the second function, we check the (new?) width of the window, and apply event listeners if it meets the requirement. At last, we make sure to attach the `resetEvents()` event to the resize event, so when someone changes orientation on an iPad, he or she can still experience the events.